# Node.js: Mongoose skips update instructions in async loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

Based in an async waterfall structure (MEAN system with Mongoose), I initiate a series of actions. One of the last ones keeps giving me a headache. From a form, I post JSON data to create an author database, where also books can be linked to their authors (whereas each author document contains a field "bookids", which is an array of book ObjectIDs, hence references to other documents).
Here is the code:

```
async.waterfall([

            {...},

            //write references of books to newly created author document
            function(newBooks, newAuthor, callback){

                async.forEachSeries(Object.keys(newBooks), function (item, internalcallback){ 

                    Author.update({ _id: newAuthor._id}, { $push: { bookids: newBooks[item] }}, {safe : true}, function(err, update){
                        if(update){
                            console.log('bookId added: '+newBooks[item]);   
                            internalcallback(err);
                        }
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);   
                        }
                    });

                }, function(err) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);   
                    }
                    console.log('adding bookids to author done');
                    callback(null);
                });
            }

        ], function (err, result) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);   
            }
            console.log('DONE!!!');
            res.send('200');
        });
```

newBooks is an array of bookIDs. My problem: the loop never reliably saves (pushes) ALL bookIDs from the array into the db. If the array contains one entry, no book reference is created. If it contains three entries, two are created. I'm not sure, whether I ran into an asynchronous callback issue (database has not finished executing but code keeps going on nonetheless and does not wait for callback) or if I'm just missing something else.
I thought, the code is asynchronous-proof, but obviously it's not!?
Any suggestions?
Cheers Igor

Comment: Try forcing the safe option to true. Author.update(conditions, update, {safe : true}, callback);

Comment: Your code looks good, but you're never checking for an error.

Comment: I can't spot the immediate reason for your issue (assuming you get `DONE!!!` as expected), but it certainly is neither a good idea to do `internalCallback()` in a condition only; nor is a good idea to ignore errors - just pass them on: `internalCallback(err);`, `callback(err)`.

Comment: I am not getting any error messages whatsoever but I just had some more test runs and now got a sneaking suspicion that it's got something to do with the asynchronous environment. I just saw from the output messages, that the previous function was still filling the array while I got the "adding bookids to author done"-message which is not even supposed to be executing until filling the array is complete. Maybe I should switch from async.waterfall to async.series?